# Where is gradle installed on my windows?

Tags: gradle

I am doing this at the moment

```
C:\Users\kaunjovi                              
λ for %i in (gradle.bat) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
C:\myInstalls\gradle-4.6\bin\gradle.bat
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 18):

## Gradle installation directory:

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

If you use SDKMAN, then it will be the following

```
$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/
```

## UPDATE:

Then go to your command prompt. Run the following command to get the .gradle directory

```
dir /S /P .gradle
```

Comment: My question was about how to find installation directory in case someone had installed in a non standard location. Specifically for windows.

Comment: Thanks for the update @skywalker. However, I am seeing some .gradle in my C:\Windows\System32. It has some files that seems to be used for creating locks. Is that the same that you have?

Comment: Actually If you have .gradle in System32 folder, then you may have some access problem. Sometimes it may need administrator permission. So on that case, you can delete .gradle folder and uninstall it. Then reinstall again and check that the .gradle is exists in C:\Users\<username>\.gradle location or not. If it is found in this location, then it is OK.